# How to sell prepaid cards (Like Recharging cards) on Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2

I am searching for a way to sell prepaid Recharging cards on Magento2.

Customer purchase the product and pay on my store, if the payment is complete, he got the prepaid Recharging card Code (16 digits) by email or any other way.

I have searched a lot. I didn't find any result.

**Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of gift voucher extensions available

You might have to change wording in templates and emails to say card (not voucher)

But essentially you are generating a 16 digit card number as a voucher with a set amount when someone buys the voucher product type

https://amasty.com/gift-card-for-magento-2.html

The above extension is good as you can manage a balance